# How do I use htaccess to make a short URL to a MediaWiki page?

Tags: htaccess, url, apache, url-rewriting, mediawiki

I'd like to rewrite `/liam` to `/index.php/Liam_Edwards-Playne`. I've currently written this below in the appropriate .htaccess file but it is still returning a 404:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^/liam$ %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/index.php/Liam_Edwards-Playne [NC,L]
```

Comment: BTW, the manual: https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:Short_URL

Answer (score 2):

You shouldn't need the DOCUMENT_ROOT variable. Simply doing:

> RewriteRule ^liam$ /index.php/Liam_Edwards-Playne [NC,L]

is sufficient for mod_rewrite

Comment: +1 Just to add, `%{DOCUMENT_ROOT}` could perhaps be used as part of the substitution in a server (virtualhost) context, but in a directory (.htaccess) context the substitution path must be _relative_ to the DOCUMENT_ROOT, so it should be omitted.

Comment: It's not working, still getting a 404.

Comment: Double check that mod_rewrite is enabled.

Comment: Remove the slash at the start of the pattern. `^/liam$` becomes `^liam$`. (In .htaccess files the directory prefix is removed when pattern matching.)

Comment: @w3d Oops!  Grumble, grumble need moar coffee, grumble.

Comment: Grr it's still not working. Here is my full .htaccess - https://gist.github.com/4543309 - The other rewrites for changing /index.php/Page to /wiki/Page are working.